# Facing Import Error while running the imported packages in jupyter notebook of VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

Error: ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_xcb_connect'

Below is the piece of code I'm trying execute

## Declarations and imports

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

The complete Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAL9T.jpg)

Thanks in advance for helping out

Answer (score 3):

I think it's related to this issue: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6015.

Running: `pip install pillow==9.0.0` should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue on Mac M1 chip with pyodbc library, I resolved this and it worked for me, hope it will helps you as well.

I managed to fix it with a `--no-binary` option which forces pip to compile the module from source instead of installing from precompiled wheel.

```
pip uninstall pyodbc 
pip install --no-binary :all: pyodbc
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to happen on Mac M1. Reverting to 9.0.0 fixes the issue.

Comment: to old OS of Mac?