# Used Migration Assistant to migrate from an Intel Mac to a newer M1 Mac. Now some of my Python programs aren't working due to ImportError

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, apple-m1, arm64

I used Migration Assistant to migrate everything from an Intel Mac to an M1 Mac. Now, when I attempt to run the python program Tiling_2023, which uses `matplotlib`, I get the following error:

```
> python Tiling_2023.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ryan/My Corner/Projects/Python/Tiling/Tiling_2023.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy as np, itertools as it, bisect as b, copy, math, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, matplotlib.ticker as mticker, functools, os
  File "/Users/Ryan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/Users/Ryan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/Users/Ryan/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Users/Ryan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Ryan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/Ryan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))
```

How do I fix this? I tried pip uninstalling matplotlib and installing it again using `pip install --no-binary :all: matplotlib` as suggested on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969116/facing-import-error-while-running-the-imported-packages-in-jupyter-notebook-of-v) about a potentially similar-sounding issue, but that did not work. I'm using Python version 3.10.0 with pyenv.

Comment: Don't use "no-binary", because you need the new binary.  An ordinary uninstall / reinstall should do it.  Note that the problem here is in PIL, not in matplotlib.

Comment: I tried an ordinary uninstall/reinstall of `matplotlib` first, without the no-binary; that didn't fix the issue. I also tried uninstalling/reinstalling `PIL`; I wasn't able to do that (it said `WARNING: Skipping PIL as it is not installed.`, so then I tried pip installing `Pillow`, which also did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you uninstall pillow before reinstalling?  Or do `pip install --force`?  The solution is going to be in re-installing any packages that have binary libraries.  To be certain, you might actually want to delete your local Python and start from scratch.

Comment: I did uninstall pillow before reinstalling, and I also tried pyenv uninstall 3.10.0 and then pyenv reinstall 3.10.0. Those didn't work. However, I just now did `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib`, which did work.

Comment: What should I do now? Delete this question? Or submit what I wrote as an answer and then accept it?

Comment: Tough call.  I'm guessing this issue will come up again, so I guess I would argue that you make an answer and accept it.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib` fixed the issue by forcing pip to reinstall matplotlib and all its dependencies.

Comment: for what it's worth conda is really good at managing this kind of nonsense